# Constructor won't run for pointer-to-object

Tags: c++, casting

I'm getting the following error:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'context_init *'
>   Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

on the following piece of code:

```
int main()
{
    context_init* Display(1280, 720, "Test_Window");
    glfwSetKeyCallback(Display.window, key_callback);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(Display->window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(Display->window);
    }

    Display->~context_init();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in the constructor in the 3d line of the program and it appeared when I rewrote my context_init instance as a pointer to an object of that class. The compiler won't run the constructor. Anybody know why the fact that I have a pointer-to-class object matters to the constructor and how to rectify the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: With a pointer you need to `new`/`delete` or use a smart pointer and functions to do them for you (`unique_ptr`/`make_unique`, `shared_ptr`/`make_shared`), but why do you want to make it a pointer?

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution to another problem and I'm trying different approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`context_init* Display(1280, 720, "Test_Window");` is a malformed attempt to assign a stack allocated instance to a pointer without using the "address-of" operator.

Possibly you mean

1. `context_init Display(1280, 720, "Test_Window");`

or

2. `context_init* Display = new context_init(1280, 720, "Test_Window");`

If you use `new`, make sure you balance it with a `delete` else you'll *leak memory*. In the case of (1), the destructor will be called when `Display` goes out of scope. In the case of (2), the destructor is called when the object is `delete`d: either way there's no need for you to attempt to call the destructor explicitly which is what I think you're trying to do with `Display->~context_init();`

Comment: I think `Display` is the variable and `context_init` is the type.

Comment: @T.C. Yes I'm inclined to agree (I've switched it), although the case convention would sit better with `Display` being the type and `context_init` being the variable.

Comment: Yeap, Display is the object and context_init is the class type. I'll try your "new" approach and see what I get

Comment: ...of course you were right about new/delete. And in retrospect I also agree with your comment about the naming convention :P

Comment: Also, don't do `Display->~context_init();`.  Either use `delete` if you `new`'d, or do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the info the destructor guys. Still a lot to learn.